# Downloading a file with Chinese characters in the name in Django with HttpResponse

Tags: django, file, download, cjk

I want to download a file with Django's `httpresponse` method. The name of the file has some special characters, like Chinese. I can download the file with the following code, but the file name appears as "%E6%B8%B8%E6%88%8F%E6%B5%8F%E8%A7%88%E5%99%A8%E6%B3%A8%E5%86%8C%E9%A1%B5%E9%9D%A2.jpg".

Could anyone tell me how to convert the file name?

```
response = HttpResponse(attachment.file, content_type='text/plain',mimetype='application/octet-stream')

response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename="+urlquote(filename)
return response
```

**Edit**:

Another problem comes out when using `smart_str`, the file name can be displayed normally in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE: in IE it's still displaying some unknown characters. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---solved by use `urlquote` and `smart_str` differently in IE and other browsers.

Comment: Did you try without calling urlquote ?

Comment: yes, but without urlquote, unicode error will display

Comment: You should replace "attachment by u"attachment i think ... also try force_unicode instead of urlquote (from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode)

Comment: i use smart_str, it works ,thank you!!!

Comment: Browser compatibility is a mess about Content-Disposition, please look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/216777/1586797

Answer (score 2):

I think it may have something to do with [Encoding Translated Strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#translated-strings)

Try this:

```
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(filename)
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me to solve your problem.

```
from django.utils.encoding import escape_uri_path

response = HttpResponse(attachment.file, content_type='text/plain',mimetype='application/octet-stream')

response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename*=utf-8''{}".format(escape_uri_path(filename))
return response
```

Comment: Are you saying, "the following code works for me to solve your problem"?  If so, can you explain how so the OP can apply it to their issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no interoperable way to encode non-ASCII names in Content-Disposition. [Browser compatibility is a mess.](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/)

```
/real_script.php/fake_filename.doc
/real_script.php/mot%C3%B6rhead   # motörhead
```

please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/216777/1586797

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [bronze man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586797/bronze-man) and [Kronel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27009/kornel), I have come to an acceptable solution to this problem:

urls.py:

```
url(r'^customfilename/(?P<filename>.+)$', views.customfilename, name="customfilename"),
```

views.py:

```
def customfilename(request, *args, filename=None, **kwds):
    ...
    response = HttpResponse(.....)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'your content type'
    return response
```

your_template.html (links to the view providing the file)

```
<a href="customfilename/{{ yourfancyfilename|urlencode }}.ext">link to your file</a>
```

Please note that filename doesn't really need to be a parameter. However, the above code will let your function know what it is. Useful if you handle multiple different Content-Types in the same function.